# How to make figure captions working inside a macro?

Tags: macros, captions, texstudio

I am writing a report often having the need to insert two figures next to each other with separate figure numbers (not subfigures a,b). To speed up the process I wrote a macro but somehow the captions do not display properly:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{width=0.45\textwidth}
  \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{%<figure1%>}
    \caption{%<captionfig1%>}\label{fig:%<labelfig1%>}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{%<figure2%>}
    \caption{%<captionfig2%>}\label{fig:%<labelfig2%>}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

When I remove the captions the thing does compile.

Comment: Can you extend this to a compilable minimal example showing how the macro is defined?

Comment: The Percentage '%' characters are probably screwing things up.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are probably talking about a macro in the text editor; you have to fill up the indicated fields with the actual captions and labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I finally found the problem. Indeed the place holders, i.e. blocks denoted with %% have to be filled out, and a valid picture needs to be inserted.

When I changed `\caption{Caption text}` to `\captionof{figure}{Caption text}` it did compile and showed the correct captions.

So the working piece of code becomes:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{width=0.45\textwidth}
  \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{vpwater}
        \captionof{figure}{Vapour pressure over water [Pa] vs temperature [K]}\label{fig:vpwater}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{errorvpwater}
        \captionof{figure}{Error of vapour pressure over water [log(error)]}\label{fig:errorvpwater}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

and the working macro including the placeholders for TexStudio:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\captionsetup{width=0.45\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{%<figure1%>}
    \captionof{figure}{%<captionfig1%>}\label{fig:%<labelfig1%>}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{%<figure2%>}
    \captionof{figure}{%<captionfig2%>}\label{fig:%<labelfig2%>}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

The % sign comments parts of the code in the code view, but it is the right notation for TexStudio macro's.

Kind regards,

Ernst Jan